# PySide and menuBar on MacOSX not showing any menu entry due to naming

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside

I am trying to create a menu with PySide. This is the code

```
def _createMenus(self):
    self._menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar()
    self.setMenuBar(self._menuBar)
    self._helpMenu = self._menuBar.addMenu("Help")

    self._aboutAction = QtGui.QAction("About", self, statusTip="About", triggered=self._about)
    self._helpMenu.addAction(self._aboutAction)
```

This code does not show anything in the menu bar, except the "python" entry.
Weird enough, if I change "About" in "Aout" it displays the menu. Is there some platform dependent weirdness I should be aware of ?

Comment: I'm on windows xp and everything works fine.  Could be a platform thing.  I know this is probably a stupid question but are you sure your widget is `QMainWindow` and not `QWidget`?

Comment: @Jeff: it's a QMainWindow. I have a suspect on the origin of the problem, though. I leave some time for an answer, and if nothing comes, I will explore the details and answer to myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu items on Mac OS X can be moved automatically by Qt to the system-wide menubar depending on the action's text and/or `menuRole` property (see [QMenuBar on Mac OS X](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x) for details).

So your "About" menu item should be the first item in the application menu.